# Python NLTK FreqDist - Listing words with a frequency greater than 1000

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I'm trying to output every word that appears in my tokens more than 1000 times (> 1000) and save it to freq1000.

```
freq1000 = []

newtokens = []

for words in tokens:
    newtokens += words
FreqDist(newtokens)

fd_1 = FreqDist(newtokens)

for i in set(fd_1):
    if fd_1.count(i) == >1000:
        print(i)
```

This is my current code, I'm completly stuck after this and I'm not sure if there is a freqdist function I can use to help. I have saved the FreqDist to fd_1 successfully. I'm just unsure how to get an output of the words that appear more than 1000 times and save it to freq1000.

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Please try to format your properly to make answering your question easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the words based on the frequency count using the `freqDist.items()` like below:

```js
list(filter(lambda x: x[1]>=1000, fd_1.items()))
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works well. But, I am also trying to get just the words that have a frequency higher than 6000 save or append them to freq6000 than use .most_common(10)   on freq6000.    I'm not sure if this makes sense or not.